# Are there good tutorials on how to modify Google GWT styles?

Tags: gwt

I'm interested in GWT but find the default styles so ugly. I know CSS, but have no big idea about how to modify the GWT styles technically. A tutorial on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/12/gwt-no-need-to-shortchange-your-style.html) is a link to one introduction.  Basically, you can call "setStyleName" on your GWT widget and give it whatever CSS style you want.  Then you can do the fiddling with exact colors or whatever in the CSS file like you would normally.

Comment: I rather tend to use setStylePrimaryName instead, this way all derived styles are also automatically updated.

GWT contains now 3 example stylesheets you can use. Maybe you could take a look at those to get an idea how they work ?

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of GWT include three themes, Standard, Chrome, and Dark. If that's what you mean by "the default styles" then you can remove it by making sure that your module definition doesn't include any of these:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of your GWT application you can either:

- Choose between the default GWT styles as mentioned by Isaac
- Apply your style on specific elements as mentioned by Peter
- Or, override the GWT default style:

Each GWT widgets has a default associated style name which generally follows this naming convention : `.gwt-<className>`.

Example:

```
.gwt-Label{
  /* your css settings */
}
```

This way you can use this name in your custom css to style all labels in your application. You can check the default style name for each widgets in [GWT's Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Label.html) (CSS Style Rules).

Here is Google's tutorial for [applying styles in GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideUserInterface.html#DevGuideStyleSheets).